# Entity framework - Fill multiple object with list from database without foreach every objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to fill list from database. but list has multiple objects.

**Class1**

```
public class HotelRsRep
{
    public CountryRep country;
    public List<HotelBoardCodesRep> boardCodes;
    public List<HotelPhoneRep> phones;
    public List<HotelFacilityRep> facilities;
}
```

**Class Object**

```
List<HotelRsRep> hotelRsReplst = new List<HotelRsRep>();
```

**Tried**

```
hotelRsReplst = db.HotelBoardCodesRep.Where(p=>p.description.Equals(des)).ToList();
```

How Can i fill that hotelRsReplst object from db?

Comment: Go Google `.Select(...)`, that's like lesson 2 in using Linq...

Comment: HotelsRsRep and HotelBoardCodesRep are different classes so you can't.

Comment: @DavidG please read my problem. if not difficult, slowed by my self without posting this.

Comment: Yes, you *still* need to look at how `Select` works.

Comment: Thanks. you still need to learn how to read.Because that just not about *select*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. This way i can fill my object.

```
var hotelRsReplst  = new HotelRsRep();
hotelRepList.boardCodes  = new List<HotelBoardCodesRep>();
hotelRepList.hotel = db.HotelBoardCodesRep.Where(p=>p.description.Equals(des)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Include.

Details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: His class is different to the EF ones... so a .Select() will be needed...

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest to do it from Linq is using include

```
hotelRsReplst = db.HotelBoardCodesRep.Include("boardCodes").Include("phones").Include("facilities").Where(p=>p.description.Equals(des)).ToList();
```

Comment: His class is different to the EF ones... so a .Select() will be needed...

Comment: @Milney Is not a problem and he can use include using lamba expression like Include(hb => hb.boardCodes)

Comment: That will give him a list of HotelBoardCodesRep objects - he wants HotelRsRep objects....

Comment: oh.. that's true my bad ^^'